# How long does it take the German KMK to evaluate a degree and what are the criteria?

Tags: degree, germany, international

I am awaiting my evaluation of my degree by the KMK ([*Kultusministerkonferenz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kultusministerkonferenz)). I paid the 200 Euro fee a month ago and am still waiting for a response. It is mentioned on their website that it takes three months for processing. Does anyone have any experience with this? Will it really take that long? And what is the probability of failing the evaluation? What are the criteria that they look into? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If they say that it takes 3 months, why worry after 1 month?

Comment: Waits are always anxious mate :) Just wanted to check if there's anyone who got it done quickly.

Comment: Sounds utterly ridiculous that the KMK would review individual foreign degrees. Just the kind of thing these crackpots might actually think up. ;) Have you got a link for a German taxpayer to read up on this procedure?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the wait times, but the goal of the evaluation is to ensure that your degree is comparable to the equivalent degrees offered by German universities. They will be looking at things like the number of credits in your major, and if you have training in the field sufficient to be equal to the German counterparts. The grades will also be considered.

The odds of "failing" are impossible to judge, but if you're short on credits or have a low grade-point average, you are likely to run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation mate. Do you know any instances where people got the results prior to the mentioned 3 months? :)

Comment: @mayooran First, may I suggest you to not call random people "mate"? Then, even if there were such an instance, it would be totally useless to conclude anything about your case.

Comment: First of all, I would like to apologize for the "mate" thing and thank you very much for your taking your time in answering the question.